# Grouping rows and selecting highest ID in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sql-order-by

I have this table below:

```
 +----+--------+------------+-----------+-------+
 | id | UserID | LoginDate  | LoginTime | Login |
 +----+--------+------------+-----------+-------+
 | 31 |     21 | 10/28/2020 | 9:32:36   |     1 |
 | 32 |     21 | 10/28/2020 | 10:38:30  |     1 |
 | 34 |      2 | 10/28/2020 | 11:09:48  |     1 |
 | 36 |      2 | 10/28/2020 | 11:10:09  |     1 |
 +----+--------+------------+-----------+-------+
```

I want to group by UserID and return only the rows that has the highest id value, expected output:

```
 +----+--------+------------+-----------+-------+
 | id | UserID | LoginDate  | LoginTime | Login |
 +----+--------+------------+-----------+-------+
 | 32 |     21 | 10/28/2020 | 10:38:30  |     1 |
 | 36 |      2 | 10/28/2020 | 11:10:09  |     1 |
 +----+--------+------------+-----------+-------+
```

This is my MySQL Code:

```
 SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM tbltrackerlogins ORDER BY id DESC) AS ttl GROUP BY UserID
```

I assumed the the inner select query already sorted out the result by `id` so that when it's grouped, it'll display the one with the highest ID. But the output is still like this:

```
 +----+--------+------------+-----------+-------+
 | id | UserID | LoginDate  | LoginTime | Login |
 +----+--------+------------+-----------+-------+
 | 31 |     21 | 10/28/2020 | 9:32:36   |     1 |
 | 34 |      2 | 10/28/2020 | 11:09:48  |     1 |
 +----+--------+------------+-----------+-------+
```

Comment: Does your mysql version support analytical queries

Comment: I recommend _not_ using the accepted answer, which may not even work on your MySQL version.